# Join foreign key on the same table and show parent and child

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a foreign key which points on the primary key of the same table (child - parent).

I am trying to write a query that will bring the results in the form as shown below:

```
Parent 1 
Parent 1 > Child 1
Parent 1 > Child 2
Parent 2 
Parent 2 > Child 2 
Parent 3 
Parent 4
```

I thought of left joining the table, even though I am very close for it, I haven't been able to do it. Let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is an easier solution on this.

```
SELECT 
    a.OrganizationTypeID,
    b.ParentOrganizationTypeID,
    a.Name ParentName,
    b.Name ChildName,
    CASE
        WHEN b.ParentOrganizationTypeID IS NULL THEN a.Name
        ELSE CONCAT_WS('>', a.Name, b.Name)
    END AS res
FROM
    tblOrganizationTypes a
        left JOIN
    tblOrganizationTypes b ON b.ParentOrganizationTypeID = a.OrganizationTypeID
WHERE a.DateDeleted is null
GROUP BY b.OrganizationTypeID
ORDER BY a.OrganizationTypeID , b.ParentOrganizationTypeID
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you split the two cases:

```
-- roots
select a.OrganizationTypeID
    , a.ParentOrganizationTypeID
    , a.Name
    , a.Name as childname
    , a.Name as res
from tblOrganizationTypes a
where a.ParentOrganizationTypeID is null
  and a.DateDeleted is null 
union all
-- children of roots
SELECT 
    a.OrganizationTypeID,
    b.OrganizationTypeID,
    a.Name ParentName,
    b.Name ChildName,
    CONCAT_WS('>', a.Name, b.Name) AS res
FROM tblOrganizationTypes a
JOIN tblOrganizationTypes b 
    ON b.ParentOrganizationTypeID = a.OrganizationTypeID 
where a.DateDeleted is null 
ORDER BY OrganizationTypeID, ParentOrganizationTypeID;
```

You can easily transform it into a recursive CTE if you want deeper nesting

I modified your [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6a0886cc02da3c4c62a96ee50d68cd1)

Answer (score 2):

Please remove `Group by` clause from your query.

```
SELECT 
    a.OrganizationTypeID,
    b.OrganizationTypeID,
    
    a.Name ParentName,
    b.Name ChildName,
    CASE
        WHEN b.ParentOrganizationTypeID IS NULL THEN a.Name
        ELSE CONCAT_WS('>', a.Name, b.Name)
    END AS res
FROM
    tblOrganizationTypes a
    left join    
    tblOrganizationTypes b on a.OrganizationTypeID=b.ParentOrganizationTypeID 
    or (a.ParentOrganizationTypeID is null and a.OrganizationTypeID=b.OrganizationTypeID)
where a.DateDeleted is null and b.Name is not null
ORDER BY a.ParentOrganizationTypeID , b.OrganizationTypeID
```

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table tblOrganizationTypes (OrganizationTypeID int, ParentOrganizationTypeID int, Name varchar(100),DateDeleted date);
 insert into tblOrganizationTypes values(1,null, 'parent',null);
 insert into tblOrganizationTypes values(2,1, 'child 1',null);
 insert into tblOrganizationTypes values(3,1, 'child 2',null);
 insert into tblOrganizationTypes values(5,null, 'parent 5',null);
```

Query:

```
 SELECT 
     a.OrganizationTypeID,
     b.OrganizationTypeID,
     
     a.Name ParentName,
     b.Name ChildName,
     CASE
         WHEN b.ParentOrganizationTypeID IS NULL THEN a.Name
         ELSE CONCAT_WS('>', a.Name, b.Name)
     END AS res
 FROM
     tblOrganizationTypes a
     left join    
     tblOrganizationTypes b on a.OrganizationTypeID=b.ParentOrganizationTypeID 
     or (a.ParentOrganizationTypeID is null and a.OrganizationTypeID=b.OrganizationTypeID)
 where a.DateDeleted is null and b.Name is not null
 ORDER BY a.ParentOrganizationTypeID , b.OrganizationTypeID
```

Output:

| OrganizationTypeID | OrganizationTypeID | ParentName | ChildName | res |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | parent | parent | parent |
| 1 | 2 | parent | child 1 | parent>child 1 |
| 1 | 3 | parent | child 2 | parent>child 2 |
| 5 | 5 | parent 5 | parent 5 | parent 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=59568831d4ea93c9d1aa28a24ff47340)*

Comment: That is showing the children twice. However, what I want to do is to show the parent once and then the subsequent children https://imgur.com/a/90K9hLA

Comment: Please share some sample data.

Comment: Let's say there is a parent `parent` with two children: `child 1` and `child 2`. The query should return 3 records. `parent`, `parent > child 1`, `parent > child 2`.

Comment: I have seen the update. However, when I add a new parent without any children it should show the parent once: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86118a22c16165b8c1968c2eac97cf85

Comment: @csandreas1 I have revised my answer